# How to div hide and show by single click using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two `div`s. I need to show one at a time.

```
<div ng-show="viewdiv">
</div>
<div ng-show="adddiv">
</div>

<a style="" href="#" ng-click="viewdiv=true" >View</a>
```

How to set `adddiv = false`? by this same `ng-click`.

`ng-click="viewdiv=true,adddiv=false"`

Is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Use only one variable like `viewdiv`  and use it like

```
    <div ng-show="viewdiv">
    </div>
     <div ng-show="!viewdiv">
     </div>

    <a style="" href="#" ng-click="viewdiv=true" >View</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using semi-colon to separate statements will work

`<a style="" href="#" ng-click="viewdiv=true;adddiv=false" >View</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">test </button>
<div ng-show="showDiv" >
   Div
</div>
```

See sample snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/26537/)

Comment: first initialize what is showDiv? it is string boolean where it is?

Comment: No need to initialize.See this snippet https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/26537/

Comment: yes works. All users didn't have code readablility stuff. using ng-init is the best way to init the variable first and use it

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div ng-show="viewDiv">
  div1
</div>
<div ng-show="!viewDiv">
  div2
</div>
<a style="" href="#" ng-click="viewDiv = !viewDiv" >Click</a>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.viewDiv = true;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/y9wy70ng/

---

Additionally you may play with

```
<a style="" href="#" ng-click="viewDiv = !viewDiv">Change to 
   <span ng-show="viewDiv">div2</span>
   <span ng-show="!viewDiv">div1</span>
</a>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sdp9t96b/

Comment: This should be the way to do that.

Comment: Edited (ng-click moved to <a>).